# Map 'close application' to mouse wheel click on XFCE panel

Tags: xfce, kill, xfce-panel, mouse-wheel

I like mousewheel clicking to close tab on firefox, great idea, and I'm now so used to it that I expect it to happen on XFCE panel applications. Which obviously it doesn't. Is there any way I can map it to do so? I suspect I wouldn't want it to close whichever app was focused if not mousing over the panel, since (e.g.) that would close firefox rather than closing the specific tab.

Does anyone know how one might go about this? Cheers

p.s. sorry this is XFCE & not Ubuntu native, but I imagine there's a good amount of overlap.